# asyncio client session GET with JSON in body

Tags: python, python-asyncio

If I use the `requests` library this works for me doing a GET request with JSON in the body:

```
import requests

x = requests.get(url, json=my_rtu_read)
print(x.status_code)
print(x.json())
```

Testing out asnycio client I cant figure out why this doesnt work even with [referencing the documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#json-request):

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

url = 'http://10.200.200.223:5000/bacnet/read/multiple'

my_rtu_reads = {
    "read": 
      [    
        {
          "address": "10.200.200.27",
          "object_type": "binaryOutput",
          "object_instance": "3"
          },
            {
            "address": "10.200.200.27",
            "object_type": "binaryOutput",
            "object_instance": "4"
          },
          {
            "address": "10.200.200.27",
            "object_type": "binaryOutput",
            "object_instance": "5"
          },
          {
            "address": "10.200.200.27",
            "object_type": "binaryOutput",
            "object_instance": "6"
          }
      ]
}

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, json=my_rtu_reads) as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            print(await resp.text())

asyncio.run(main)
```

I get a coroutine error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/BBartling/Desktop/rtuTestAsync.py", line 41, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 37, in run
    raise ValueError("a coroutine was expected, got {!r}".format(main))
ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <function main at 0x000002359898C8B0>
```

Any tips appreciated not alot of wisdom here...

Comment: Change the last line of code to `asyncio.run(main())`. `main` should be called to become a coroutine object.

Comment: Ok chaning that to just `main()` that will give me this error: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'main' was never awaited`

Comment: This works I just posted an answer but not really sure if it is overkill at all...

Comment: I suspect you changed `asyncio.run(main)` to `main()`. It needs to be `asyncio.run(main())`.